# Use Apache Hadoop JAR files or vendor specific?

Tags: java, hadoop

I am creating an application for Hadoop which should run on all Distributions of Hadoop provided by different vendors like: Cloudera, MapR, Hortonworks, Pivotal...etc. My application would be deployed on application servers like WebLogic, JBoss or can be deployed on tomcat also.
So my question here is:- Suppose some version of all these vendors use the same underlying Hadoop version say Hadoop 2.0, so should i use the JAR files given by these vendors or use the JAR files given by Apache hadoop?

I mean the JAR files that have the same classes as Apache hadoop but have their name in them like **`blablaCDH5.2blabla.jar`**, so should i use this one or the one from Apache? So i can build a single version for Hadoop 2.0 and use it for all vendors. Can that be done or i have to build different flavours of my app for all vendor distributions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: From my experience you would have to build separately for each distribution. You can't count on certain classes and functions to be the same in all different jars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how deep into hadoop API you are threading.

If your application only submits jobs to the cluster, you are probably ok with vanilla libraries as long as you stick to one specific version. If you are doing advanced stuff and using hadoop internals, it may be necessary to include vendor specific ones.

Comment: i see, so it would be safer to go with vendor specific. As i might be using some functions that the vendors might have changes according to their requirements.

Comment: If it is not too hard for you to produce different flavors of your application then that is the safer way to go. Also note that vendors are never adding their own changes the hadoop code (at least I've never heard of that happening) but only back-porting patches from newer versions to achieve new functionalities.

Comment: can you give me an example when you say using hadoop internals

Comment: Well, that is difficult to define. I'd first associate that with stuff from hadoop-hdfs, then all the YARN stuff as it was really not built for end users, and finally some things from hadoop-mapreduce that are not exposed to public. There are @InterfaceAudience annotations on hadoop classes that can help you sort out the "internal" ones.

Answer (score 2):

One approach, which may vary slightly based on your version control and build systems, would be to have separate build scripts using the dependencies from the different distributions.

Where test cases fail for a given distribution you could have a branch/fork for that distribution or, probably less desirable, have a specific build which does some pre-build magic for that distribution.

This way you should be able to maintain a consistent trunk while being able to track and handle issues that come up in vendor/version specific distribution going forward. This would definitely be possible with git and most build systems (e.g gradle, maven or ant).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a shims layer that allows your application to run with any hadoop distribution.As most of the distribution has different hadoop versions it is very difficult to deal with this problem.So most of the vendors are now creating shims layer that can work with any hadoop distribution.Shim layer has now been implemented in many applications  like Pentaho,hive,gora etc.

Answer (score 0):

Dennis you can build your application using jars provided by Apache Hadoop , because all of them are modified form of Apache hadoop. These all distributions have  same baseline structure so using jars provided by Apache hadoop won't create any problem.
In fact I am providing you links for cloudera  in which they are using jars provided by Apache Hadoop itself.[This the required link.](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/latest/CDH-Version-and-Packaging-Information/cdhvd_topic_8_1.html)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But I was telling from my experience. Please correct me where I am wrong